# With which part of my pinkie should I hit the piano keys?

Tags: piano, technique, fingering

I've recently started learning Chopin's *Fantaisie – Impromptu* in C# minor for piano on my own.

The left hand nearly always plays the same pattern, with the pinky hitting the lowest tone. The pattern (I'm lacking a professional term) is really popular in many classical pieces, especially Chopin's, it looks like this:

[image: Bass figure consisting of: root, fifth, octave, tenth, octave, fifth]

Now, I'm wondering how the pinkie should hit the piano keys, should it be with the tip only, or should one lay it completely down? The latter seems a bit more comfortable to me, but I feel like it loses precision. What is the best way to play with the pinkie, if one exists?

Comment: For the benefit of non-Americans, I think ‘pinkie’ or ‘pinky’ is the smallest, fifth finger — called the ‘little finger’ in some other parts of the world.

Answer (score 7):

You definitely do not want to play with the side of your fifth finger, on either hand. It is better to play with the pads and/or the tips of your fingers when possible.

The flatter your hands become, the less leverage you have from the big knuckles (the joints between the metacarpals and the first phalanges) and therefore the less control and authority you have with playing. Also when your wrist falls as your fingers flatten you have less arm weight available to use. When you have less arm weight available you have to compensate with tension from the flexor digitalis muscles and that will both slow you down and increase your risk of injury.

Resist the desire to flatten. Keep an empty space under your hand. Find a teacher to give you at least one or two lesson, over Zoom if you have no other options.

One last note: the use of the phrase "hit the piano keys" concerns me because the technique is never about hitting or striking the keys. We play the keys and we press the keys. The finger should always be touching the key before we play it, and you can't hit or strike something you're already touching. When you see a famous pianist lifting their hand high in the air before playing a loud note, that is specifcally done for visual effect and if you could watch in super slow motion you'd see they bring their hand down until they touch the key and there's the most minuscule pause and then they play the key the exact same way they would if their hand had never left the keyboard. Do not hit or strike keys. Touch them to prepare and then play them.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer. Just one remark to the last paragraph: i was taught to lift the hand when playing staccato. I remember exercises like playing scales staccato to learn to hit the right keys even from above.

Comment: Very good point about the misleading theatrics of big arm gestures... :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I remember flattening the pinkie always in Chopin's Nocturne Opus 9 No1 and I feel like this was bad as I've been experiencing the exact problems you pointed out. The formulation about hitting the keys is just a mistranslation,  of course it's pressing ;). I'll definitely look out to get some piano lessons in future. Thank you again!